# How to hide/show buttons in WPF pages?

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I have a slider menu in WPF and i have 2 buttons for show and hide it.And the menu denified in MainWindow that's mean it's visible in all pages but i need to hide the buttons in some pages like in login page.This is my code behind of my slider menu :

```
  private void BtnTopMenuHide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowHideMenu("sbHideTopMenu", btnTopMenuHide, btnTopMenuShow, pnlTopMenu);
    }



    private void BtnTopMenuShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowHideMenu("sbShowTopMenu", btnTopMenuHide, btnTopMenuShow, pnlTopMenu);
    }

    private void ShowHideMenu(string Storyboard, Button btnHide, Button btnShow, StackPanel pnl)
    {
        Storyboard sb = Resources[Storyboard] as Storyboard;
        sb.Begin(pnl);

        if (Storyboard.Contains("Show"))
        {
            btnHide.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            btnShow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else if (Storyboard.Contains("Hide"))
        {
            btnShow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            btnHide.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

    }
```

For example I have a method for log out

```
 private void LogOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string SessionFile = @"C:\somefile\CFG\session.dat";
        File.Delete(SessionFile);
        MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/LoginPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        ShowHideMenu("sbHideTopMenu", btnTopMenuHide, btnTopMenuShow, pnlTopMenu);
        btnTopMenuHide.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        btnTopMenuShow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

when I click the logout button it's hidding buttons and also i have login success method like this :

```
 MainWindow _main = new MainWindow();

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsConnected.CheckConnection();
        if (loginService.SessionData().Success() && loginService.SessionData().NotExpired())
        {
            _main.btnTopMenuHide.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            _main.btnTopMenuShow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/PaymentPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

in this method if login success it's navigating the page but not showing the buttons also when I try to create an object from MainWindow it's creating but if I close the application it's still running background because of object how I solve this problems or any ideo for a diffirent way to hide this buttons ? I hope I explaind everythigs thank you.

Comment: While the code-behind you posted can do the job, the *WPF* way is the XAML markup. You can show and hide your menu and any buttons using different `Trigger`s: a `Trigger` for a property value, a `DataTrigger` for a bound view-model property value and an `EventTriger` for an event.

Comment: How can I know is the page is loaded or not ? I've tried IsLoaded property and MouseOver but they didn't worked. and I'm new in wpf so can you give a simple example or suggest a tutorial about it ? Because I never used Triggers that you are talking about .

Comment: You should really use MVVM, and have your top-level button control a property in a supporting viewmodel, and then have each of the other views bind to that same property indepently

Comment: Do you want display some buttons on the PaymentPage or what is your issue?

Comment: yes when i debug my app  the buttons setting to visible in `if (loginService.SessionData().Success() && loginService.SessionData().NotExpired())` but they not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't creat an object like

> `MainWindow _main = new MainWindow();`

From MainWindow.This code creating a new window but I don't need a new MainWindow.I need to create an object form current window.So we should create an object from ***Current MainWindow*** like

> `MainWindow wnd = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;`

then we can use like

> `wnd.btnTopMenuHide.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;`

. Thats it.This worked for me I hope help the others!